# IIS 7.5 Windows authentication for multiple applications on same server

Tags: iis-7.5, windows-authentication

This question surely have been answered before. We need to develop a SSO solution for a client and until they have installed ADFS (which will take some time)...

Our application runs on 4 different applications/ports on the same IIS. We have tried setting authentication mode="Windows" and disabled anonymous access on all applications but receive a 401 unauthorized when the front end (port X) calls one of the backend Web apis (port Y,Z..). The problem is that the authentication is only valid for the first application (front end).

Can we pass the authentication on in some way? I've read about Intranet Zones, etc. but am struggeling a bit as to how this can be done

Comment: Windows authentication is not enough and you need to configure Kerberos delegation.

Comment: Ok, I've found a few good ms-articles. Will check them out. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benjaminperkins/archive/2015/08/03/configure-application-request-routing-with-windows-authentication-kerberos.aspx and http://blogs.technet.com/b/latam/archive/2015/06/24/kerberos-authentication-and-application-request-routing.aspx

Comment: What about "Kerberos-enabled" Windows authentication with ARR. Would that solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this problem myself and found the answer the article titled [Forms Authentication Across Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc.aspx/) on MSDN

Relevant Sections Below:

> To configure forms authentication across applications, you set attributes of the forms and machineKey sections of the Web.config file
>   to the same values for all applications that are participating in
>   **shared forms authentication**.
>
> Applications that run ASP.NET version 2.0 or later can share forms
>   authentication ticket information with earlier versions of ASP.NET if
>   you include decryption="3DES" in the machineKey element for each
>   ASP.NET version 2.0 (or later) application.